# Items is undfiend In Kendo Grid group

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

This is how I declaring my kendo grid

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<LogModel>()
        .Name("ChangeLog")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(m => m.dateTimeChangeDate)
                 .ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("#=console.log(items)#")
                .Title("Date and Time")
                .ClientTemplate("#= ChangeDate#")
                .Width("12%");
            columns.Bound(m => m.Component)
                .Title("Component")
                .Width("8%")
                .Filterable(filterable => filterable.UI("componentFilter")
                .Extra(false)
                .Operators(operators => operators
                    .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                    .Contains("Contains")
                 ))
            );
            columns.Bound(m => m.Action)
                .Title("Action")
                .Width("15%")
                .Filterable(filterable => filterable
                    .UI("actionFilter")
                    .Extra(false)
                    .Operators(operators => operators
                        .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                        .Contains("Contains")
                    ))
                 );
            columns.Bound(m => m.Changer)
                .Title("Changer")
                .Width("10%");
            columns.Bound(m => m.Identifier)
                .Title("On")
                .Width("15%");
            columns.Bound(m => m.OldValue)
                .Title("Old Value")
                .Width("20%");
            columns.Bound(m => m.NewValue)
                .Title("New Value")
                .Width("20%");
        })
        .Filterable()
        .Selectable()
        .Sortable()
        .Groupable()
        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
        .ToolBar(toolbar =>
        {
        toolbar.Template(
            @<text>
                @*
                    The year is 2017, kendo does not have a realiable html server control for the excel button when we are using a template.
                    So we have to explicitly use the excel export command button mark up. Kendo will recoginze the k-grid-excel CSS class and configure it accoridngly.
                *@
                <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-excel" href="#"><span class="k-icon k-i-excel"></span>Export to Excel</a>
                <span style='padding-left:35%;font-weight:bold;padding-top:7px'>@ViewBag.ProjectNumber</span>
                <span style='float:right;font-weight:bold;padding-top:7px'>Total: <span id="change-log-record-count">@ViewBag.ChangeLogRecordAmount</span> records</span>

            </text>
            );
        })
        .Excel(excel => excel.AllPages(true).FileName(@ViewBag.ChangeLogType + " Change Log " + @ViewBag.ProjectNumber + ".xlsx").Filterable(true))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
             .Ajax()
             .Model(model =>
             {
                 model.Id(p => p.Id);
             })
             .Read(read => read.Action("FetchChangeLogData", "ChangeLog")
             .Data(".buildParam"))
       )
       .Events(e => e.FilterMenuInit("eresizeFilter")
                     .ExcelExport("modifyFormatForExcel")
                     .DataBound("preselectCustomFilter"))
       .ClientDetailTemplateId("change-log-details-template")
)
```

According to this link [for kendo grid documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.groupHeaderTemplate) there is a list of fields available for me to use in the template and `items` is one of them. But when I try to group my grid I get an error that `items` is undefined. I also tried group and it is also undefined. I tried `value` and `field` and those works fine. Is there something I am missing or is this feature not fully implemented yet.

**UPDATE**
Here is an example based off of their demo in the link. I slightly modify it as a POC to demonstrate [that you can inspect items.](http://dojo.telerik.com/aPOGE)
I understand that they use Kendo UI and I am using UI for ASP.NET MVC, but that should matter that much unless it does.

**Update #2**
Looks like only the `value` and `field` is working the aggregates and the items field is undefined.

**Update #3**
It seems that `.ClientGroupHeaderTemplate` may not be fully implemented yet since thier documentation mention `ClientGroupFooterTemplate` and not the other.

**Update #4**
Once I add the aggregate field `count` to the data source, I can now access it in the template.

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
             .Ajax()
             .Model(model =>
             {
                 model.Id(p => p.Id);
             })
             .Aggregates(aggregates =>
             {
                aggregates.Add(p => p.dateTimeChangeDate).Count();
             })
             .Read(read => read.Action("FetchChangeLogData", "ChangeLog")
             .Data("buildParam"))
       )
```

[Check documentation here](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/GridColumnBuilderBase#methods-ClientGroupFooterTemplate(System.String))

Comment: From what I see in the documentation you are referring the items is are all list objects which then can be filtered in order to show some text. I don't think a list of objects can be shown as string in your group header. Furthermore it would help if you showed all your grid in order to let us see the way the grouping is set too (I'm guessing group by dateTimeChangeDate?)

Comment: @AnastasiosSelmanis I updated the code to include the who grid. and while it true that is a string, the way kendo template syntax work is that `the # character is also used to signify the beginning and end of custom JavaScript code inside the template.` so it actually JavaScript. Here is an example based off of their demo. I slightly modify it as a POC to demostrate that you can inspect items. https://dojo.telerik.com/aPOGE

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned from my comment I don't think you have understood what "items" stands for. In your example if you set

```
groupHeaderTemplate: "Admin count: #=items[0].name#"
```

Your Header will show correctly "Admin count: Jane Doe". The variable "items" is a reference to the binded data. That means that it is a list of objects.
If you write items[1].age it will show 30 etc.

If you want to show the number of rows as your "Admin count" suggest you could just use

```
groupHeaderTemplate: "Admin count: #=items.length#"
```

if you want to use items instead of count aggregation.

This way it should be easier to understand how exactly to handle the variable "items" in order to show what you need to show.

Now if you have any other problem explain please what exactly do you want to show to your header?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in that fiddle:

```
groupHeaderTemplate: "Admin count: #=count#"
```

Try

```
.ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("#=count#")
```

Comment: Didn't work for me I got count undefined. But value and field works fine.

Comment: Weird...It worked in the Dojo. Take the example link and put #=count# in place of #=console.log(items)#...it shows Admin Count: 3 for me.

Comment: Yeah that's weird thing about it. It works using the Kendo UI JavaScript wrapper, but the Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC widget is not working.

Comment: I also like to point out that in their documentation `ClientGroupHeaderTemplate` is not their so maybe it is not implemented fully yet. https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/GridColumnBuilderBase#methods-ClientGroupFooterTemplate(System.String)

Comment: So the link here --> http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/aggregates does not work for you using the mvc server wrappers?

Comment: Progress!! Once I add the aggregate fields to the  dataSource I now have access to the aggregate fields `count` :) ,  but items is still undefined.